# Text Display Between multiple strings

Tags: c#, text, display

I have this text showing when the player fails to guess the right value.

```
if (guess < Joules)
{
    Joulestext.text = "Oops...entered less than minimum amount of Joules .";
}
```

But I want to have multiple texts randomly displayin in the same text field like for example either this poppin up or another saying "try using..." . How can I do that?

Comment: Create an array of messages and then using `Random` class you can pick one and show it inside `if (guess < Joules)`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is this: create an array of messages and pick one random when necessary.

```
string[] messages = new string[] {"msg1", "msg2", .... "msgn"};
Random rnd = new Random();

if (guess < Joules)
{
    var index = rnd.Next(0, messages.Length);
    var msg = messages[index];
    Joulestext.text = msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using Linq:

```
var messages = new List<string>
{
    "message 1",
    "message 2",
    "message 3",
    "message 4",
    "message 5"
    //...
};

if (guess < Joules)
{
    Joulestext.text = messages
        .OrderBy(m => Guid.NewGuid())
        .First();
}
```

To randomize the messages, they are simply ordered by new Guids.